# how to update activity2 every x seconds from activity1 in android

Tags: java, broadcastreceiver

How can i update an activity from another every x seconds

For instance on whatsapp when a user is uploading or downloading file from chat, i discover that even when that activity is close and reopen that file progress is not interrupted. so what i want to do is start downloading a file from activity one and show progress in activity two.

Note: activity one is the main activity and will always be open until the app exit but activity two can be open/close while app is still active.

Activity two is user chat while activity one is the chat list.